# QtMenuBar need assistance with "receiver" Resolved, only in previous version

Tags: c++, qt

Qt and Linux novice. From the documentation:

> insertItem(const QPixmap & pixmap, const QObject * receiver, const
>   char * member, const QKeySequence & shortcut = 0, int id = -1, int
>   index = -1)

I can create a qt window with a menu bar, and understand that the method **insertItem(...)** adds items.  The argument: **QObject * receiver** is my problem. Everything I find seems to presume I know what this  **receiver** item is. I have PDF versions of "C++ GUI Programming with QT 3", 4, and 5 and a find tells me that "insertmenu" and "insertitem" are not in the book.

Obviously this **receiver** is the target of a menu item click, but I would really like some details. Can it be any widget?  Is the widget automatically shown?  There are more questions.

In my current case, when the user clicks on a menu item named "Control" he should see a pop up dialog that provides the ability to set multiple radio buttons and line edits.

What I really want is a link to a page describes the concept of receiver and maybe provides a simple example.

Comment: I do not find in Qt4 or Qt5 the `insertItem()` method, could you point out where you found that documentation? I only find it in Qt3 which is deprecated: https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qmenudata.html#insertItem-3

Answer (score 0):

Eyllanesc's comment is correct.  We remain mostly stuck with Qt3 but have Qt4 available so I am trying to use Qt4.  I forgot and referenced the Qt3 book and tried to use that. (Two reasons: Qt 3 still works and management does not want to spend money and time to upgrade.  And, rumor has it that the Qt company now has non-US ownership and that is a problem for government projects.  I presume, but do not know, this was not the case for Qt 3 and 4.)
But we can use Qt4, I will redirect myself.

Thank you for the reply/comment and this is resolved.